# Python remove from list acting strange when used inline

Tags: python

I want to loop through a list and remove a single element at a time:

```
l1 = ["a", "b"]
for l in l1:
    l2 = l1[:]
    l2.remove(l)
    print(l2)

# ['b']
# ['a']
```

The behavior of the code changes when I use the remove call inline:

```
l1 = ["a", "b"]
for l in l1:
    l2 = l1[:].remove(l)
    print(l2)

# None
# None
```

Any idea what is happening? Is this an artefact of `remove()` or a more general issue with functions that use mutability of objects?

Thanks

Comment: `remove` does its job but doesn'r return anything (i.e. it returns `None`). So you are assigning `None` to `l2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you excecute the line:

```
l2 = l1[:].remove(l)
```

you are doing this:

```
x = l1[:]
l2 = x.remove(l)
```

As you can see you are assinging to `l2` the result of apply the method `remove` on `x`. The element will be removed, but `remove` always return `None`, that's why `l2` is `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `remove()` does not return anything. That is why `l2` is always `None` in your second example. The change is only applied to `l1`.
In your first example example the list is duplicated into `l2` and then an element is removed from `l2`.

Answer (score 3):

The below code will do the job.

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for a,b in enumerate(l1):
    l2 = l1[:].pop(a)
    print(l2)
```

and that's because **.pop()** function actually removes **and** returns it's value, in the other hand **.remove()** returns None (and that's what you get).

Happy Coding.!!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `remove()` function returns `None`, rather than the list with element removed.

Moreover, `remove()` delete the element in O(N) complexity, which is cumbersome for your demand. I prefer to adopt the following approach

```
for idx in range(len(l1)):
    l2 = l1[:idx] + l1[idx+1:]
    print(l2)
```